# How to get cartesian product from Map of String Set

Tags: java, string, dictionary, treemap

This might be similar to [Java : Cartesian Product of a List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591561/java-cartesian-product-of-a-list-of-lists) but not answering my question.

I created the following

```
TreeMap<String, Set<String>> aMapOfSet
```

`aMapOfSet` represents different words in a sentence and `Set<String>` will contain all variations to the words if there is no variation then set will be empty/null for that word key.

I want to write a method that would take aMapOfSet and returns a Set of all possible sentences.

For instance, the original sentence could be:

```
tss xes wxy xyz
```

suppose there are total of 3 variations for the word "wxy" and total of 2 variations for the word "xyz"

Then aMapOfSet would look like this

```
tss
xes
wxy -> [wxys,wxyes]
xyz -> [xyzs]
```

The answer would be 6 sentences in resultSet

```
tss xes wxy xyz
tss xes wxys xyz
tss xes wxyes xyz

tss xes wxy xyzs
tss xes wxys xyzs
tss xes wxyes xyzs
```

I used treeMap to preserve the sequence of words.

Here is my work in progress code:

```
Set<String> getCartesianProduct(TreeMap<String, Set<String>> wordVariationSet)
{
    Set<String> resultSet =new HashSet<String>();// to store answer

    for(String theOriginalWord: wordVariationSet.keySet())
    {
       for(String word:wordVariationSet.get(theOriginalWord))
       {

           // TODO create a sentence with 1 space between words and add to resultSet
       }
    }

    return resultSet;

}
```

I will update the code as I make more progress.

What is the best way to iterate through all variations, so to get all 6 sentences.

Comment: You could use Google Guava or look at its implementation. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good time to use recursion:

```
Set<String> getCartesianProduct(List<String> originalWords, TreeMap<String, Set<String>> wordVariationSet) {
    Set<String> resultSet =new HashSet<String>(); // to store answer
    varyWord(resultSet, "", originalWords, wordVariationSet, 0);  // begin recursion with empty sentence
    return resultSet;  // return result
}

void varyWord(Set<String> result, String sentence, List<String> originalWords, Map<String, Set<String>> wordVariationSet, int index) {
    if (index==originalWords.size()) {  // no more words to vary -> sentence is complete
        result.add(sentence);  // add to results
        return;  // done (return from recursion)
    }
    if (index>0) sentence += " ";  // add a space if working on any but first word
    String theOriginalWord = originalWords.get(index);  // grab original word
    varyWord(result, sentence + theOriginalWord, originalWords, wordVariationSet, index+1);  // add to sentence and vary next word
    Set<String> wordVariations = wordVariationSet.get(theOriginalWord);  // grab variations of this word
    if (wordVariations!=null)  // make sure they're not null
        for(String word: wordVariations)  // iterate over variations
            varyWord(result, sentence + word, originalWords, wordVariationSet, index+1);  // add to sentence and vary next word
}
```

I hope this code is self-explanatory. If not, let me know and I can add some detail.

A couple of things to note:

1. You wrote "I used treeMap to preserve the sequence of words.", but unfortunately a treemap sorts its keys by their natural ordering (in this case by alphabet), **not** by when they were added. That's why I included the `List<String> originalWords` as a parameter, which does preserve ordering. So, you will need to initialize that as well (make an `ArrayList` and right after you `put(...)` a word into `aMapOfSet`, also `add(...)` it to the list).
2. This code is missing a couple of checks, like a null-check for `originalWords` and `wordVariationSet`, a check whether `wordVariationSet` contains the same words as `originalWords`, ...
3. If your `originalWords`-sentence contains the same word twice, the `wordVariationSet` will not be able to handle different variations for each. Instead, your second `put(...)` will overwrite your first one.

Comment: +1, this is what I was looking for. Will test it out.

Comment: Just updated some things to note. Especially point 3 might be relevant!

Comment: You know, it would probably be easier to use an `ArrayList<Set<String>>` for your `wordVariationSet` and just add the items to it in the same order as you add the words to `originalWords`, just make sure you add empty (or null-) entries to it as needed. That way you also avoid issue 3 from above (unless, of course, you want to have exactly one set of variations for a word, even if the word shows up multiple times, in which case issue 3 would be a feature, not a bug).

Comment: Thanks! That's right, I in fact end up using `ArrayList<Set<String>> ` after posting this here. Because, as you pointed out, TreeMap wasn't giving right answer.